# How to ease writing of a (long) command

Tags: macros

I was asking myself how I can ease writing of long commands/phrases that are used very often in the exact same way.

Example: How can I write the following:

```
\begin{mdframed}\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
bla bla bla
\end{lstlisting}\end{mdframed}
```

In a shorter way like:

```
\mycommand{
bla bla bla
}
```

**Edit:**
As requested I will add an update to my origin question below:

Here is the missing style definition:

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language = C,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle = {\color{DarkGreen}\bfseries},
    morekeywords = {Send,Receive},
    mathescape=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rhookswarrow}},
    breakindent=0
}
```

So as you can see I also want to have the option for mathescape inside in order to do stuff like:

```
\mycommand{
bla bla bla $1+2=3$
}
```

Which should **not** result into text `"$1+2=3$"` but into `1+2=3` as math interpretation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that starts with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: New commands are defined by `\newcommand` statement. You can also define a new environment using `\newenvironment`. Example of both can be found in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Commands and https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Environments.

Comment: That example is build into the tcolorbox package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd not recommend making the `mdframed`–`lstlisting` into a command with argument instead of a proper environment.

For one thing, line breaks ***cannot*** be preserved in the argument version.

I'd also suggest `tcolorbox` rather than `mdframed`, because it offers better integration with `listings`. Anyway, you can do

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,mdframed}

\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}
   {\mdframed\lstset{}}
   {\endmdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}
bla bla bla
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

Note the auxiliary commands `\mdframed` and `\endmdframed`, otherwise the `\lstnewenvironment` declaration would produce something that doesn't work at all. I removed `style=mystyle` because I have no idea of how the style is defined. Add all the necessary options you need in the argument of `\lstset`.

#### Extended version with a style

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,mdframed}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{tmstyle}{
  language = C,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle = {\color{DarkGreen}\bfseries},
  morekeywords = {Send,Receive},
  mathescape=true,
  columns=fullflexible,
  prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rhookswarrow}},
  breakindent=0,
}

\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}
   {\mdframed\lstset{style=tmstyle}}
   {\endmdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}
Send bla bla bla $1+2=3$
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to use `\surroundwithmdframed{mylisting}` as advertised by `mdframed` manual?

Comment: @ArashEsbati That's an alternative. However, I'd go for `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Adding my own defined style is not working. Also adding e.g. `$1+2=3$` is not working. Any idea?

Comment: @PIC-Nico Without seeing how `mystyle` is defined it's difficult to test. What do you expect from `$1+2=3$`?

Comment: Yep, you're right:

\lstdefinestyle{tmstyle}{
 language = C,
 basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
 keywordstyle = {\color{DarkGreen}\bfseries},
 morekeywords = {Send,Receive},
 mathescape=true,
 columns=fullflexible,
 prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rhookswarrow}},
 breakindent=0
}

Comment: @PIC-Nico Please, edit your question with the details

Comment: @PIC-Nico Anyway, I see nothing strange when I add the declarations of the style and `style=tmstyle` to the definition of `mylisting`; the output is as expected; for instance `$1+2=3$` is typeset as math and the keyword `Send` is typeset in dark green.

Comment: Yes you're right. I am a noob (typo in stylename). Thx a lot!

Comment: @PIC-Nico You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

With the upcoming LaTeX kernel, due to be released in October, you can add to 'hooks' to achieve this. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/before}{\begin{mdframed}}
\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/after}{\end{mdframed}}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
bla bla bla
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

(You'll need to run e.g. `pdflatex-dev` at present for this to work: that uses the pre-release version of the kernel.)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can do something like this:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
  \begin{environment}
   #1
  \end{environment}
}
```

However, the `lstlisting` environment relies on changing category codes to work so the category codes won't be what they need to be when the argument is expanded.

Fortunately, this is something that was foreseen as an issue. Instead, you'll need to use the `\lstnewenvironment` command so you could do something like:

```
\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}
   {\begin{mdframed}\lstset{style=mystyle}}
   {\end{mdframed}}
```

and then use it with

```
\begin{mylisting}
bla bla bla
\end{mylisting}
```

Comment: For some reasons this breaks my compilation. No PDF is being generated at all if I use this environment. The error messages are absolutely not helpful :-(

Comment: Did you try? I guess you didn't because it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @egreg I rarely try my solutions.

Answer (score 2):

As long as `\mycommand` is used on document-level only, not from within arguments of other macros, not from within definition-texts of other macros, not from within token-registers, not as part of a a moving argument, you can have LaTeX read things as verbatim-arguments and pass these to `\scantokens`.

But I cannot recommend this because indenting the code that is to be displayed will definitely not be easier this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
    language = C,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle = {\color{DarkGreen}\bfseries},
    morekeywords = {Send,Receive},
    mathescape=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rhookswarrow}},
    breakindent=0
}


\newcommand\mycommand{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^I=12 %
  \newlinechar=\endlinechar
  \MyReadVerbatimArgument
}%
\begingroup
\NewDocumentCommand\MyReadVerbatimArgument{+v +v}{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\MyReadVerbatimArgument{+v}{%
    \scantokens{\endgroup#1##1#2}%
  }%
}%
\MyReadVerbatimArgument|\begin{mdframed}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
||
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
%|

\begin{document}

\mycommand{bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
bla bla bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

If you wish, this can be extended to remove a leading endline-character from the entire verbatim-argument if present and a trailing endline-character from the entire verbatim-argument if present.

This way

```
\mycommand{
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
This line is not indented.
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
}
```

and

```
\mycommand{           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
This line is not indented.
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
}
```

and

```
\mycommand{
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
This line is not indented.
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla}
```

and

```
\mycommand{           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
This line is not indented.
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla}
```

will all yield the same output.

The tricks for removing a leading/trailing endline-character, i.e., a leading/trailing `^^M`-character of category code 12(other)=a leading/trailing return-character of category code 12(other) are the same as the tricks for a removing leading/trailing space-token from a macro-argument.
With the helper-macros just don't use space-tokens as argument-delimiters but use explicit return-character-tokens of category code 12(other).

The latter (removal of a leading/trailing space) is discussed in Exercise 15 of Michael Downes' "Around the Bend"-collection of TeX challenges.

A pdf-file by Peter Wilson containing all challenges/exercises and all solutions/answers belonging to the "Around the Bend"-collection of TeX challenges can be found at:
[http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/challenges/AroBend/AroundTheBend.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/challenges/AroBend/AroundTheBend.pdf#chapter.15)

The original text of the challenge/exercise can be found at:
http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/challenges/aro-bend/exercise.015

The original text of the discussion of submitted solutions/answers can be found at:
http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/challenges/aro-bend/answer.015

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}


%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
%% Begin of code for  \UDRemoveLeadingNTrailingEndl
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\@firstoftwo{\expandafter}{} \@firstoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo{\expandafter}{} \@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Exchange arguments
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UDExchange[2]{#2#1}%
\begingroup
% Dummy-definition, will be overridden. Is used only to get ^^M of 
% category code 12(other) as #1 into subsequent definition-texts:
\NewDocumentCommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl{+m}{%
  \endgroup
  %%===========================================================================
  %% Check whether_verbatimized_ argument starts with a endline-character
  %%===========================================================================
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                            {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                              which is to be checked>'s 1st token is a
  %%                              endline-charactern>}%
  %%                            {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                              which is to be checked>'s 1st token is not
  %%                              a endline-character>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl[1]{%
    \UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl\UD@SelDom##1\UD@SelDom#1\UD@@SelDom
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl{%
    \long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl##1\UD@SelDom#1##2\UD@@SelDom{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
  %%===========================================================================
  %% Remove one leading endline-character from _verbatimized_ argument
  %%===========================================================================
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@TrimLeadingEndl{\long\def\UD@@TrimLeadingEndl#1{}}%
  %%===========================================================================
  %% Check whether _verbatimized_ argument ends with a endline-character
  %%===========================================================================
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                               which is to be checked>'s last token is a
  %%                               endline-charactern>}%
  %%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                               which is to be checked>'s last token is not
  %%                               a endline-character>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl[1]{%
    \UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl##1\UD@SelDom#1\UD@SelDom\UD@@SelDom
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl{%
    \long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl##1#1\UD@SelDom##2\UD@@SelDom{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
  %%===========================================================================
  %% Remove one trailing endline-character from _verbatimized_ argument
  %%===========================================================================
  \newcommand\UD@TrimTrailingEndl[1]{\UD@@TrimTrailingEndl##1\UD@SelDom}%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@TrimTrailingEndl{%
    \long\def\UD@@TrimTrailingEndl##1#1\UD@SelDom{##1}%
  }%
  %%===========================================================================
  %% Remove one leading and one trailing endline-character from _verbatimized_ 
  %% argument if present. Due to \romannumeral0-expansion the result is
  %% delivered in 2 expansion-steps:
  %%===========================================================================
  \newcommand\UDRemoveLeadingNTrailingEndl[1]{%
    \romannumeral0%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl{##1}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl{##1}{%
         \UDExchange{ }{%
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
         }%
         \expandafter\UD@TrimTrailingEndl\expandafter{\UD@@TrimLeadingEndl##1}%
       }{%
         \UDExchange{ }{\expandafter}%
         \UD@@TrimLeadingEndl##1%
       }%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl{##1}{%
         \UDExchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
         \UD@TrimTrailingEndl{##1}%
      }{ ##1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Now let's change the catcode of ^^M and then call the dummy-definition
%% of \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl so that it can fetch the catcode-12-^^M,
%% close the group, override itself and define all those macros where that
%% catcode-12-^^M  is needed:
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl{^^M}%
\makeatother
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
%% End of code for  \UDRemoveLeadingNTrailingEndl
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language = C,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle = {\color{DarkGreen}\bfseries},
    morekeywords = {Send,Receive},
    mathescape=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rhookswarrow}},
    breakindent=0
}

\newcommand\mycommand{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^I=12 %
  \newlinechar=\endlinechar
  \MyReadVerbatimArgument
}%
\begingroup
\NewDocumentCommand\MyReadVerbatimArgument{+v +v}{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\MyReadVerbatimArgument{+v}{%
    \scantokens\expandafter{\romannumeral0%
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UDExchange
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
       \UDRemoveLeadingNTrailingEndl{##1}%
     }{ \endgroup#1}#2}%
  }%
}%
\MyReadVerbatimArgument|\begin{mdframed}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
||
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
%|

\begin{document}

\mycommand{
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
This line is not indented.
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
}


\mycommand{           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
This line is not indented.
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
}


\mycommand{
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
This line is not indented.
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla}


\mycommand{           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla
This line is not indented.
           bla bla bla
           bla bla bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Some remarks about subtleties with the ways in which TeX works:*

*TeX's mechanism for reading and tokenizing input in any case discards all space-characters at the end of a line of .tex-input and then adds a character whose coding-point-number in the TeX-engine's internal character-encoding scheme (which either is ASCII with traditional engines or is UTF‑8/Unicode with engines based on XeTeX/LuaTeX; ASCII can be considered a strict subset of Unicode) equals the value of the integer-parameter `\endlinechar` before starting to tokenize that line. Usually the value of the `\endlinechar`-parameter is 13, denoting the return-character which in TeX's `^^`-notation is also accessible as `^^M`. (M is the 13<sup>th</sup> letter in the latin alphabet.)*

*This implies that .tex-input-lines containing space-characters (ASCII 32(dec)/Unicode 32(dec)) only will in any case be treated as empty lines.*

*This also implies that with .tex-input-lines ending with space-characters (ASCII 32(dec)/Unicode 32(dec)) these space-characters will be discarded.

You can test this by putting lines of text that end with a sequence of space-characters into the `verbatim*`-environment.*